# Using php values in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, database

My friend made a Javascript file that projects a graph of random values it generates from 1-20.

```
var value1 =  (Math.random() * 14).toFixed(0);
```

I made a PHP file that reads values from an SQL database and assigns that value to $number variable.

How can I assign variable value1 the value of $number.
I tried using:
`var value1 = <?php echo json_encode($number); ?>;`
but it's not working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: If the type of `$number` is number then you don't need to call `json_encode()`. If it is not number then `json_encode()` helps you produce correct JavaScript (without syntax errors) but `value1` becomes a string and adding it with another value (string or number) produces unexpected results.

Comment: *"but it's not working for me."* -- this is definitely not helpful. Describe the actual outcome and the expected outcome. Post the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply include `var value1 = <?php echo $number; ?>;` in your script.